# No speed improvement for OpenCV 3.0 with OpenCL

Tags: performance, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencl

I am trying to speed up opencv 3.0 using opencl in windows. I have an integrated GPU. Opencv specs predicts a speed increase of 10 times for sobel operator for iGPU.
But it is giving me actually a speed decrease of 1 sec compared with cpu. The
code and the machine specifications are given below. Can anyone explain this and give me tips to increase the speed.

### Code (in qt 5.6)

```
void OpenCLTest::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    UMat oclImage;
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
        tr("Open Image"), ".",
        tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"));
    Mat regImage = cv::imread(fileName.toStdString());
    regImage.copyTo(oclImage);

    double t = (double)getTickCount();


    // speed test - start
    Sobel(oclImage, oclImage, -1, 1, 1, 9);
    // speed test - end


    t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Times passed in seconds: " << t << endl;
}
```

I have checked for ocl using "cv::ocl::haveOpenCL()" and its working fine.
The image used is 24 bit 800x600, res is 96 dpi.

The time measurements for cpu and gpu are

**cpu - 0.121774 sec**

**gpu - 1.14634  sec**

Specifications:

Os: Windows 7 64 bit

CPU - AMD C-60 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics , Speed - 997 MHz

GPU - AMD Radeon HD 6290 Graphics

opencl - OpenCL 1.2, Loveland compute units:2@275MHz

Ram - 6 gb

Compiler - mingw 4.92

IDE - QT 5.6 (qt creator)

Thanks

Amal

Comment: Did you measure time of many iterations (e.g. 100)? OpenCL runtime initialization takes a lot of time at first time.

Comment: Hello @akarsakov,                                                                              Thanks a lot . It worked. The new time measurements are given below for 100 iterations. The opencl is definitely faster in this case                             Times passed in seconds for CPU : 18.645
Times passed in seconds for GPU : 1.75226                                             Thanks                                                                                                           Amal